# SQL injection: Validate that SQL was parameterized correctly, and has ? where it should

Tags: sql-injection

A framework that I've built lets the application coder create sql dynamically (when they need to). If they use the tool correctly, then they will proceed in two steps: 1. build the sql (PreparedStatement) with '?' placeholders, and 2. pass all user-entered data as parameters to the PreparedStatement.

This is just the usual means of using a PreparedStatement and params, to avoid sql injection. Nothing special there.

But, I want to go an extra step: I want to verify that the coder has 'parameterized' correctly. In what sense is that possible, if at all? Can one determine syntactically all places where a '?' *should* appear in the SQL? Does such a tool already exist?

Edit:
Example:

select blah from x 
where a='user-data'
and b=?

Here, a has not been parameterized, while b has. I want to detect the 'a' kind of malformed sql. Does that make sense?

Comment: you're using the word "injection" yet you appear to not even know what that it means ... your post is highly confusing - are you trying to do SANITY CHECKS or are you trying to PREVENT INTRUSION (via injection) ??

Comment: I have added a clarifying example.

Comment: Your example is not using parametrized SQL (at least not java); it is looking for a literal value of `?` in b. Also, injection can only happen when you construct SQL dynamically from an external source; you are not doing that, you are looking for literal strings.

Comment: Thanks - I have corrected the example. The example 'pretends' that the coder has incorrectly placed user-data as a literal into the string; the string is then passed to PreparedStatement; remember, this is an example of an error I'm trying to catch.

Comment: The whole idea is flawed. It fails reality check. As a special note, it will eventually allow an injection even if used as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, some of your premises are flawed.
Namely

- "pass all *user-entered data* as parameters" is a sure way to injection. The moment developer started to separate his data to "safe" and "unsafe", he is busted.
- The whole idea won't work. Sometimes we have to add constant strings into queries. And you'd never can tell if it was a flaw or all right.

If you don't trust your developer *so much* - there are 2 possible fool-proof solutions, for the price of reducing his ability of using SQL to some limited subset:

- let them use [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) only
- or limit them to an [ORM](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord) or a [Query Builder](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries)-based solution only

The idea is to limit your developer to these sandbox-based solutions only (dunno if such a limitation is possible out of the box though).

The above solutions are closer to your initial idea *and feasible*.

Comment: I don't think the idea of looking for an extra form of protection - defense in depth - is flawed. But I agree that the answer is "No, this won't work", for the exact reason you state.